# Manipulating UIView layer's CATransform3D and UIView's CGAffineTransform at the same time

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

This might sound like a weird question, but what I am trying to do isn't very strange. I am currently resizing a UIView via the view's CGAffineTransform like this:

```
self.selectedController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, resizeRatioValue, resizeRatioValue);
```

Where the resizeRatioValue is a value between 0.7-1.0, depending on the location of the gesture. This works great. With a pan gesture, I am able to shrink down my view beautifully.

Now, I would like to add another twist to this. As the view is shrinking, I would like to apply a rotation to the view (similar to the coverflow effect) so that it rotates and shrinks **at the same time**.

I can rotate the view just fine using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732474/985027) code:

```
float angle = 45.0 * progressRatio;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 2000; // Perspective
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform,
                                                      1 * angle / (180.0 / M_PI), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
self.selectedController.view.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

But when I put both of these together, it's one or the other. Whichever one occurs second is the one that works. I can't get them to coexist.

What can I do to make it so that these can both work together? Or is there a completely different approach that would be better suited for what I am trying to do?

Comment: UIView.transform is a wrapper around CALayer.transform. This is why you see it is one or the other. You need to create scale transform with CATransform3DScale and combine it with the rotation transform for example with CATransform3DConcat. Then assign the transform to view.layer.transform.

Comment: Thank you! Just the direction I needed.