# Does transform will cause UIView's frame to be undefined?

Tags: ios

[Developer document] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) 
says if you apply a transform which is not identity to UIView, it will cause the frame to be undefined.

[image: https://i.v2ex.co/oPYdB72s.jpeg]

But after i try in Playground, i found the frame will change correctly after apply a transform to UIView? So what do i missed?

Here is the code i used to test:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Photos

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))

view.frame
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
view.layoutIfNeeded()
view.setNeedsDisplay()
view.frame
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: In other words, you log view.frame and find the width and height to be 200.0?  Can you demonstrate that here with the log output and the logging code?

Comment: @danh yes， i pasted the output.

Comment: Yes but try a rotation.

Comment: Well, I guess the intent of the doc is that you shouldn’t rely on the frame being right in all circumstances. I’d bet $1 that a rotation will cause an incorrect or invalid frame.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says “undefined” to tell you not to rely on the `frame` having any particular value if a non-identity `transform` has been applied. Maybe they don't compute it in a consistent way, or maybe they just don't want to explain how it's computed, or maybe they just want the freedom to change how it's computed.

However, once upon a time, I figured out the undocumented behavior of `frame` when a non-identity `transform` is applied, and it may still be computed the same way now. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724031/ios-catransform3d-coordinates/8732474#8732474).